# ContactsContract select records by phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor, contactscontract

I can select all contacts using the query below

```
    cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > 0";
    String orderBy = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, orderBy);
```

However, I have a phone number list and I want to create this query like

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.PhoneNumber_or_something_else  in (MyPhoneNumberArray)
```

Is that possible to do this?

A worst-case scenario, I can remove the related item using do while after I create my cursor, but, as far as I know, I cannot remove any record from the cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Contacts DB is organized in three main tables:

1. `Contacts` - each entry represents one contact, and groups together one or more `RawContacts`
2. `RawContacts` - each entry represents data about a contact that was synced in by some `SyncAdapter` (e.g. Whatsapp, Google, Facebook, Viber), this groups multiple Data entries
3. `Data` - The actual data about a contact, emails, phones, etc. each line is a single piece of data that belongs to a single `RawContact`

All phone numbers in the Contacts DB are in the `Data` table, so that's what you need to query, you can get the list of `CONTACT_ID`s from that query and use it to get general info about contacts if you need.

```
String[] phonesList = new String[] { "+121212345" }; // will work better if all phones in this list are in e164 format

String[] projection = { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER };
String selection = Phone.NUMBER + " IN ('" + TextUtils.join("','", phonesList) + "') OR " + 
                   Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER + " IN ('" + TextUtils.join("','", phonesList) + "')";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String phone = cur.getString(2);
    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + phone;
}
```